# How to remove google synced data from my phone?

Tags: sync, google

I added my father's Google account in my android phone to help him in some work as his phone wasn't working. Now before I could stop the sync settings, it has synced some contacts in my phone with his data. Can I remove the data from my android phone which has been synced from his account?

Answer (score 0):

If the contacts remain after you removed the account, you should be able to remove them clearing your contacts storage app cache.